# How do I assign vector of vectors of strings using pointers to multiple vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I need help figuring out bits of code. I am not sure how to populate vector> using pointers to multiple vectors of strings.

Please make suggestions only on lines that contain //HELP NEEDED HERE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string>* pointerReturner (string str1, string str2, string str3)
{
    vector<string> *vList = new vector<string>();
    vList->push_back(str1); 
    vList->push_back(str2);
        vList->push_back(str3); 
    return vList;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    vector<string> *vMakeList1;
        vMakeList1 = pointerReturner ("1","8-20-2011","Ford");

        vector<string> *vMakeList2;
    vMakeList2 = pointerReturner ("2","8-20-2011","Honda");

        vector<string> *vMakeList3;
        vMakeList3 = pointerReturner ("3","8-20-2011","Toyota");

        vector<vector<string>> *MakeList;

        //HELP NEEDED HERE

delete vMakeList1, vMakeList2, vMakeList3;


    vector<vector<string> >::iterator i = MakeList->begin();
    for( ; i != MakeList->end(); ++i)
    {
        vector<string>::iterator pos = (*i).begin();
        for ( ; pos!=(*i).end(); ++pos)
            cout << *pos << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The results is the `vector<vector<string>>` populated with relevant data.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating your containers with `new`?  That's not right at all:  just declare it as a local variable and return it by value.

Comment: All right, let's see if there is someone who actually knows.

Comment: I know what [copy elision](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+elision) is. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MakeList = new vector<vector<string> > ();

MakeList->push_back(*vMakeList1);
MakeList->push_back(*vMakeList2);
MakeList->push_back(*vMakeList3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You would need a `vector<vector<string>*>* MakeList`. And, holy too many pointers and `new` Batman.

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
vector<vector<string>> *MakeList = new vector<vector<string>>();
MakeList->push_back(*vMakeList1);
MakeList->push_back(*vMakeList2);
MakeList->push_back(*vMakeList3);
```

would seem to do the job.

This is not the way to do things, but you seem to be aware of that already.

Comment: Yeh, giving credit to netudki, do I need to delete the vector<vector<string>> after I use it?

Comment: Anything you new, you need to delete.

Comment: what is the problem with doing things this way? it works fine.

Comment: @seaworthy: The problem is that you're making your job much more difficult than it has to be by manually managing memory.  And If you continue to write code this way, you're bound to have memory leaks with anything of less trivial complexity.  Is there a reason you are using pointers and dynamic allocation like this?  Do you believe that it improves performance?